# Suspend process according to CPU temperature in Windows 8

Tags: cpu, process, automation, temperature, suspend

Is there is a software or a way to suspend a process according to the CPU temperature? Sometimes when I render video the CPU temperature increases a lot, so I have to suspend the process in resource monitor in Windows, but I would like to automate this with software.

Comment: I think the important thing is why is something so CPU intensive causing your processor to become so hot that you're concerned it'll damage it... Have you cleaned the heatsink and fan? Have you got your case in a well ventilated location? Have you considered upgrading the heatsink and fan for better heat dissipation knowing you do a lot of CPU intensive activity...?

Comment: -1 You should not have to do this. The CPU is **designed** to be fully used for extended periods of time. You should check your cooling and case airflow.

Comment: @kinokijuf While you are correct, sometimes there is a need for a practical solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user has a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/171857)

Comment: @kinokijuf Using a stock cooler on a new second gen i7 is in not sufficient to keep your CPU cool for this type of activity (I've tried). Rendering video will use all of your cores for hours and the temp WILL slowly creep up. You could spend money and buy a good 3rd party cooler OR you can use a solution such as the one I've given. The OP has given you all of the information you need in order to understand the problem (which IS the 'How to Avoid' solution proposed in the link you gave).

Comment: @krowe Does the OP have a case fan?

Comment: @kinokijuf The question being asked is always legitimate at some point. Get an N2 cooled system and someone is going to want to OC that system until it overheats simply because they can. At some point, it will always be unfeasible to use cooling to solve heat issues. If CPUs didn't get hot or if it didn't matter how hot they got then we wouldn't bother to cool them. Heat is the problem, cooling is one solution. This question addresses the heart of the matter while a question about how to have better cooling is simply perfecting the Band Aid.

Comment: @krowe No. Let me repeat: the CPU is designed to be running continuously under proper cooling. Any kind of throttling, which the OP proposes, is the band-aid.

Comment: @kinokijuf At best, that is your opinion. It is an opinion which flys in the face of the engineers who made the CPU capable of being overclocked and the consumers who demand that functionality. There are also many aftermarket cooling manufacturers (and those who buy them); all of which seem to think that stock cooling isn't always good enough. Also, don't get me wrong, a good Band-Aid is a wonderful thing; it still doesn't beat not getting the cut in the first place though.

Answer (score 11):

This solution will require the programs, [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) and [PsSuspend](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

1. First create a batch script that will do what you want. Something [like](http://ss64.com/nt/pssuspend.html):

   ```
   pssuspend \\yourPCName vlc
   ```

   Replacing the parameters with the correct values for your situation. Test this to make sure it is suspending your jobs correctly.
2. Now, go to the SpeedFan configure dialog and select the 'Events' tab. Then, create an event to launch the script when your criteria are met:

[image: SpeedFan configure dialog]

**Note**: This picture is from a similar event I created which used a VBS script. Your BATCH file location would go in the box which shows `wscript.exe` and the next box (the parameters) would most likely be blank.

As you can see, SpeedFan calls my CPU, 'AUX'. SpeedFan is a little bit buggy but it'll do what you want more or less. One thing to look out for is that the two numeric up\downs on the second line of event configuration don't seem to work at all. They don't even save properly so I'd say to forget about them and use your script to manage multiple instances.

**Note**: pssuspend with the `-r` switch can also be used to resume the job once speedfan detects the machine is cool again.